# Updating password with BCrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

When I login with a username and password by BCrypt checks no problem, everything is fine.

But when I go through the process of recovering password and try to login with the new password the BCrypt never returns true.

The code I have is as follows:

```
before_save :encrypt_password
before_update :encrypt_password

def authenticate
   player = Player.find_by(mail: self.mail)
   unless player.nil?
   current_password = BCrypt::Password.new(player.password)
   if current_password == self.password
    player
   else
     nil
   end
 end
end

private
def encrypt_password
    unless self.password.nil?
    self.password = BCrypt::Password.create(self.password)
end
```

I'm using rails 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need the `before_update` callback.**

When creating a new record (user in this case), only `before_save` is triggered. So you get the right behavior.

But when updating a record, both `before_update` and `before_save` are triggered, which means your `password` column is encrypted twice. That's why you get unexpected behavior.

Check [this page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for more information about callbacks.

---

What's more, I think it's a bad idea to make `password` a real column in database. All you need is a column called `encrypted_password` in database and making `password` a virtual attribute.

So you can write `encrypt_password` method like this:

```
def encrypt_password
    unless self.password.nil?
    self.encrypt_password = BCrypt::Password.create(self.password)
end
```

Which gave you no chance to make a mistake like you just made.

Comment: Yes, it's working now!! thank you very much is that I'm just starting out in Rails

Comment: Ok! I get it! thnk again!