# Unable to update password with Bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I've tried this many ways but it seems BCrypt is encrypting a users submitted password twice.

When a user signs up- Bcrypt works great, and I am able to sign in. But when I try and update their password in my password_resets_controller, I'm no longer able to log in. My database shows that the password is being updated and hashed, but I can't sign in.

I even removed the line `@customer.save`, yet my database is still showing that the password is being updated !

Is something being updated under the hood I'm not aware of? See relatd SO thread:
[Updating password with BCrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773350/updating-password-with-bcrypt)

**In my Customer.rb**

```
require 'bcrypt'
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    @customer = Customer.find_by_email(email)
    if @customer && @customer.password == password
      return @customer
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
end
```

**In my customer_controller, the create code that actually works**

```
  require 'bcrypt'
 class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  def create_customer_account_iphone
  @customer_count = Customer.where(email: params[:email]).size rescue nil
  if(@customer_count == 0 || @customer_count == nil ||)
    @customer = Customer.new(first_name: params[:first_name], email: params[:email])
    @customer.password = params[:password] //this calls my model methods
    @customer.save  //here I am saving
    unless (!@customer.save)
     respond_to do |format|
      msg = {:status => "SUCCESS", :messages => "Customer created", :data => @customer.as_json}
      format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      msg = {:status => "FAILED", :messages => "Customer Not Saved"}
      format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
    end
  end


def sign_in_iphone
@customer = Customer.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
unless (@customer == 0 || @customer == nil)
  respond_to do |format|
    msg = {:status => "SUCCESS", :message => "CUSTOMER", :data => @customer.as_json}
    format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
  end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      msg = {:status => "FAILED"}
      format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

**In my password_reset_controller**

```
class CustomerPasswordResetsController < ApplicationController

   def edit
 @customer = Customer.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
end


def update
@customer = Customer.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
if @customer.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  redirect_to new_customer_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password  reset has expired."
else
  @customer.password_hash = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password])
  # @customer.save
  unless !@customer.save
    redirect_to new_customer_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password has been reset!"
  else
    render :edit
  end
 end
end
```

**In my password_reset.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @customer, :url => customer_password_reset_path(params[:id]), :method => :patch  do |f| %>
<% if @customer.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @customer.errors.full_messages %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Update Password" %></div>
```

Comment: Try `@customer.update_attributes(:password_hash, BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password]) )`

Comment: Is there something in your model code that touches this field?

Comment: @tadman can you be more specific? There is something in my model actually I will post

Comment: I can't see anything here that looks wrong, so my suspicion is you have some kind of code in the model that's touching `password_hash` somehow.

Comment: @tadman, maybe its in the customer_controller update definitions? I can post those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your form the new password will be in `params[:customer][:password]` not `params[:password]` - your existing code always sets the password to nil.

Changing the password resets controller update action to instead do

```
 @customer.password = params[:customer][:password]
```

should do the trick. As a side note the commented out `customer.save` doesn't matter because you save again on the next line.

Next time something like this happens consider using the debugger to examine what is happening in your action - it would be easy enough to spot that the password was being set to nil. The [debugging guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) has lots more tip on this.

Comment: This worked ! Thanks, will definitely read up on the debugging guide. As of now I am flying blind

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you're assigning `password` as well as doing some post-processing with `password_hash`. The way this is intended to be used is via `password` alone if you have the model code with that `password=` method. This means you won't need to do any additional work beyond simply assigning it.

What you want in your `password_reset` method is:

```
@customer.password = params[:password]
@customer.save!
```

That should take care of it by running it through the appropriate model code.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this first and it didn't work. Just reset it to this and it still doesn't work. For refernce I essentially copied the 2nd half of this railscast with the Bcrypt gem intsructions http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password & https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby

Comment: Also the .save isn't even necessary ! It saves regardless. I find this odd and a sign some callbacks is affecting this. Would `  before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` affect anything

Comment: The first thing to check, as always, is if there's anything interesting in `log/development.log`. A `save!` should be required since I don't see anything in the `password=` method that does that.

Comment: I agree, but I just removed the .save! and the password in the DB still changes to a new hash. Would the `patch` method having something to do with this ?

Comment: I also just added my sign in method (I'm using my models `authenticate` method. This only works when I create an account. Once I update the password It always returns `FAILED`

Comment: The method used only triggers different actions, but not how the records are handled. You really need to look more closely at `log/development.log` to see what's going on in there, in particular the queries that are or aren't being run, and the actions being executed.